# PHP Encode message length as 2 byte hex for XML socket post

Tags: php, xml, string, sockets, hex

I am dealing with an XML socket server which I receive and send XML requests from/to.

The server requires a 2 byte hex prefix to the string that indicates the length of the message; the message I receive when connecting to the XML socket is as follows:

XML String received

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Iso8583PostXml>
<MsgType>0800</MsgType>
<Fields>    
<Field_007>xxx</Field_007>
<Field_011>xxx</Field_011>
<Field_012>xxx</Field_012>
<Field_013>xxx</Field_013>
<Field_070>001</Field_070>
</Fields>
</Iso8583PostXml>
```

String converted to HEX

```
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
```

You can see starts with "0101" when I convert it to hex, which is the length of the XML message sent.  To decode this message in to XML, I convert it to a hex string and then chop off the first 4 characters, it then works in simplexml_load_string - if I dont remove that "0101" the XML doesn't parse - even though if I echo out the string received it looks like normal xml with nothing prepending it.

The response I send back is an XML string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Iso8583PostXml>
<MsgType>0810</MsgType>
<Fields>
<Field_007>xxx</Field_007>
<Field_011>xxx</Field_011>
<Field_012>xxx</Field_012>
<Field_013>xxx</Field_013>
<Field_070>001</Field_070>
<Field_039>00</Field_039>
</Fields>
</Iso8583PostXml>
```

This has a length of 322, what I need to do is prefix this length as a 2 byte hex value to the string and send the message back, the same as the message I received.

Does anyone know how I can set that 322 hex header to the string?

[UPDATE]

I've tried doing the following:

```
$hex_string = bin2hex($length.$xml);
$send_xml = pack('H*', $hex_string);
echo "Sending acknowledgement...\n";
$result = socket_write($socket, $send_xml, $length);
echo $send_xml;
```

The $send_xml is outputting the length as a string in front of the XML

```
322<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Iso8583PostXml>
<MsgType>0810</MsgType>
<Fields>
<Field_007>0813063726</Field_007>
<Field_011>093726</Field_011>
<Field_012>093726</Field_012>
<Field_013>0813</Field_013>
<Field_070>001</Field_070>
<Field_039>00</Field_039>
</Fields>
</Iso8583PostXml>
```

Which is not working.. I somehow need to write that 322 in to a 2 byte prefix for the xml string

Answer (score 1):

Try below code its working great for me

```
function sendSocketRequest($XmlString, $Socket_Request) {
    if (!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    if (!socket_connect($sock, $Socket_Request['HostName'], $Socket_Request['Port'])) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    $status = socket_write($sock, pack_int32be(strlen($XmlString)), 4);
    $status = socket_write($sock, $XmlString, strlen($XmlString));
    $response = socket_read($sock, $this->_socketReadLength);

    socket_close($sock);
    return substr($response, 2);
}

function pack_int32be($i) {
    if ($i < -2147483648 || $i > 2147483647) {
        die("Out of bounds");
    }
    return pack('C4', ($i >> 24) & 0xFF, ($i >> 16) & 0xFF, ($i >> 8) & 0xFF, ($i >> 0) & 0xFF
    );
}
$socketResponse = sendSocketRequest($yourXMLString, array('HostName'=>'<HostName>','Port'=>'<Port>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check php function pack (http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) with formats h or H depens on your Endianness of your XML socket server.

But it should give you a push into the right direction